# Getting matching items in lists based on nullable properties

Tags: c#, null

I'm iterating through two lists to find matching objects. The objects have two string properties, `Id1` and `Id2` below. If `Id1` is not `null`, empty or whitespace, I want to use it to find a matching object in the other list. Otherwise I want to make use of `Id2`.

If both `Id1` and `Id2` are set to null by the extension method on either `p` or `p2`, I want to skip the iteration, since I know that I won't find a match.

```
public static string NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : value;
}
```

```
foreach (Product p2 in productList1)
{ 
    Product match = productList2.FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string pId = p.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ??
                     p.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();

        string p2Id = p2.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ??
                      p2.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();

        if (pId == null || p2Id == null)
            return false;

        return pId.Equals(p2Id);
    });

    // do stuff with match
}
```

This seems to work, but it feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel here. Are there any built in methods that I can make use of to simplify the code? Perhaps a class that implements `IEqualityComparer`?

Example use case:

```
List<Product> list1 = new List<Product>()
{  
    new Product() { Id1 = "123", Id2 = null },
    new Product() { Id1 = "435", Id2 = null },
    new Product() { Id1 = null, Id2 = "123" }
}

List<Product> list12 = new List<Product>()
{  
    new Product() { Id1 = "123", Id2 = null },
    new Product() { Id1 = "456", Id2 = null },
    new Product() { Id1 = null, Id2 = "123" }
}

// do something with each matching item in the first list
// which would be item #1 and item #3 above
```

Comment: It isn't very clear to me what you're attempting to do but I feel like this can be greatly simplified with a few lines of LINQ. Can you give some sample input/output so I can add it to my answer?

Comment: You can replace `NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace` with the built-in method [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) (although you'll have to change the logic around a little). As it is right now it's hard to follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Does my update help?

Comment: Just noticed that your question mentions two lists, but your code only uses one (`products`).

Comment: @mjolka Woops, typo. Sorry - I'll update

Comment: `p2` is from list 1 while `p` is from list 2. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start refactoring!

```
foreach (Product p2 in productList1)
{ 
    Product match = productList2.FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string pId = p.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ??
                     p.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();

        string p2Id = p2.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ??
                      p2.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();

        if (pId == null || p2Id == null)
            return false;

        return pId.Equals(p2Id);
    });

    // do stuff with match
}
```

`p2Id` does not depend on `p`, so let's move it out of the lambda.

```
foreach (Product p2 in productList1)
{ 
    string p2Id = p2.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ??
                  p2.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();

    Product match = productList2.FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string pId = p.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ??
                     p.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();

        if (pId == null || p2Id == null)
            return false;

        return pId.Equals(p2Id);
    });

    // do stuff with match
}
```

Now let's define a method on `Product` to remove the repetition. I called it `GetKey`, but there's probably a better name.

```
public string GetKey()
{
    return this.Id1.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace() ?? this.Id2.NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace();
}

foreach (Product p2 in productList1)
{ 
    string p2Id = p2.GetKey();

    Product match = productList2.FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string pId = p.GetKey();

        if (pId == null || p2Id == null)
            return false;

        return pId.Equals(p2Id);
    });

    // do stuff with match
}
```

It looks like you actually want to call `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in `NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace`, so let's fix that.

```
public static string NullIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value;
}
```

Actually, we don't need to go through `productList2` if `p2Id` is null.

```
foreach (Product p2 in productList1)
{ 
    string p2Id = p2.GetKey();
    if (p2Id == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    Product match = productList2.FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string pId = p.GetKey();

        if (pId == null)
            return false;

        return pId.Equals(p2Id);
    });

    // do stuff with match
}
```

Given that we only use `p2` for its key, we can rewrite this as

```
foreach (var key in productList1.Select(product => product.GetKey()).Where(key => key != null))
{
    Product match = productList2.FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string pId = p.GetKey();

        if (pId == null)
            return false;

        return pId.Equals(key);
    });

    // do stuff with match
}
```

Now let's use a dictionary to replace the call to `productList2.FirstOrDefault`.

```
var firstProductWithKey = new Dictionary<string, Product>();
foreach (var product in productList2)
{
    var key = product.GetKey();
    if (key != null && !firstProductWithKey.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        firstProductWithKey.Add(key, product);
    }
}

if (!firstProductWithKey.Any())
{
    return;
}

foreach (var key in productList1.Select(product => product.GetKey()).Where(key => key != null))
{
    Product match;
    if (firstProductWithKey.TryGetValue(key, out match))
    {
        // do stuff with match
    }
}
```

So what have we gained? Hopefully the intention of the code is a bit clearer, but there's also a performance benefit.

Let's say that the lists have \$n\$ and \$m\$ elements respectively, and that there are no keys common to the two lists.

In the original code, we're evaluating each key in the first list \$m\$ times, and each key in the second list \$n\$ times. So \$2nm\$ keys in total.

In the refactored version, we evaluate each key in the first list once, and each key in the second list once, for \$n + m\$ keys. We're performing much less work, and generating much less garbage for the GC.

Comment: I think the key here (no pun intended) is the `Key` property. What do you think about a custom `Equals` method (or similar) as a method on the `Product`, that uses the new `Key`? Thanks for the input!

Comment: You can make a custom method, but don't call it `Equals`. Save that for when you really need to compare items for complete equality. I think it would be better to create a new interface and implement it. But ask yourself: What does a custom method get you beyond just comparing the property?

Comment: @Snowbody Okay. I figured that it might be handy if I extend the id check later on, by let's say, introducing a third property. Then I can update the logic in one common place.